# Botão "Sair" em aplicação desenvolvida no App Framework

Tags: android, html5, eclipse

Como criar um botão "Sair" ou fazer com que a aplicação feche ao utilizar o "voltar" do Smartphone?

Para desenvolver a minha aplicação estou utilizando o [App Framework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) da Intel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa ter em mente o modo de funcionamento do Android e as recomendações do Google sobre design de aplicativos.

O Android é desenvolvido para que o usuário não se preocupe se um aplicativo está aberto ou fechado. O próprio sistema operacional decide quando encerrar um aplicativo baseado nos recursos de memória e processamento que o sitema possui no momento. A partir do momento  que o usuário para de usar o aplicativo, o mesmo entra numa fila para ser encerrado em caso de necessidade. O Android funciona assim para que um usuario possa alterar rapidamente entre aplicativos.

Existe o método `finish()`. Você pode criar um botão que chama diretamente este método, mas o que ele vai ter o mesmo efeito do uso do botão voltar, que é esconder a sua activity e deixá-la no modo "parada" (chamando o método onStop()). O que realmente fecha a activity é metodo `onDestroy` que deve ser chamado somento pelo sistema.

Resumindo, aplicações para Android não tem e não devem ter um botão **sair**. Olhe as aplicações do Google (Gmail, hangout, play music, gplus, calendar etc) nenhum deles tem um botão sair.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Olá amigo, poderia explicar um pouco mais sobre sua solução?